# I have this identity that I'd like to prove. $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\frac{n-2k}{n}\binom{n}{k}\right)^2=\frac{2}{n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

I have this identity that I'd like to prove.
$$\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{n}\bigg(\dfrac{n-2k}{n}\binom{n}{k}}\bigg)^2=\dfrac{2}{n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}$$

Here's what I have done so far: (using a binomial indentity)

$$=\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{n}\bigg({\binom{n}{k}-2\binom{n-1}{k-1}}\bigg)^2}$$
$$=\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{n}\bigg({\binom{n-1}{k}-\binom{n-1}{k-1}}\bigg)^2}$$
$$=\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{n}\bigg({\binom{n-1}{k}-\binom{n-1}{k-1}}\bigg)^2}$$

At this point I expanded the square, *Here's where I made a mistake*

$$=\displaystyle{{\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k}^2+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}}^2-\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n}}\binom{n-1}{j-1}\binom{n-1}{i}$$

$$=\displaystyle{{\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k}^2+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}}^2-\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n}}\binom{n-1}{j-1}\binom{n-1}{i}$$

$$=\displaystyle{2\binom{2n-2}{n-1}-\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n}}\binom{n-1}{j-1}\binom{n-1}{i}$$

because I can separate the  sums
$$=\displaystyle{2\binom{2n-2}{n-1}-2^{2n-2}}$$

Clearly, at some point here I made a stupid mistake. I was hoping someone will point the error to me and perhaps give me a hint. I prefer hints to complete solutions. Thank you for your time.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3710884/combinatorial-argument-for-a-binomial-idenity for a combinatorial proof.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I have seen that but I want to prove it algebraically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After expanding the square, the summation index should be the same for the last summation, making it a single summation over $i,$ not a double summation with $i,j.$ You then have a sum which can be evaluated with Vandermonde's identity.

Comment: could you expand on why it should be a summation over $i$?

Comment: @crystal_math When you expand, you have a summation over $k$ of the term $-2 \binom{n-1}{k} \binom{n-1}{k-1}.$ For some reason, you decided to change $k$ to $i$ and $k-1$ to $j-1,$ but $k, k-1$ are not independent.

Comment: $(\sum_{k}a_k+b_k)^2=\sum_k a_k^2+\sum_k b_k^2+2\sum_{i<j} {a_ib_j}$  Isn't this the indentity?

Comment: @crystal_math Your parentheses are inside the summation though.

Comment: Yup. I'm dumb. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would have followed a slightly different approach, let us see if it is really faster.
 Clearly we have $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2=\binom{2n}{n}$ by Vandermonde's identity, and similarly

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}k(n-k)\binom{n}{k}^2=[x^n]\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}x^k\right)^2=[x^n]\left( n^2 x^2 (1+x)^{2n-2}\right)=n^2\binom{2n-2}{n-2}. $$

Since $(n-2k)^2 = n^2-4k(n-k)$ it follows that

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}(n-2k)^2\binom{n}{k}^2 = n^2\binom{2n}{n}-4n^2\binom{2n-2}{n-2} $$
and it just remains to perform some simplification. Yeah, it looks faster.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\color{#44f}{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\bracks{\pars{n - 2k \over n}
{n \choose k}}^{2} = {2 \over n}{2n - 2 \choose n - 1}}:\
{\large ?}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\bracks{\pars{n - 2k \over n}
{n \choose k}}^{2} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{n - 2k \over n}^{2}
{n \choose k}\
\overbrace{\bracks{z^{n - k}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}}
^{\ds{{n \choose n - k} = {n \choose k}}}
\\[3mm] = &
\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}
{n \choose k}\pars{1 - {4k \over n} + {4k^{2} \over n^{2}}}z^{k}
\\ = &
\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}
\bracks{1 - {4 \over n}\pars{z\,\partiald{}{z}} + {4 \over n^{2}}
\pars{z\,\partiald{}{z}}^{2}}\
\overbrace{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}z^{k}}
^{\ds{\pars{1 + z}^{n}}}
\\[3mm] = &
\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}
\braces{\pars{1 + z}^{n} - 4z\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1} +
{4 \over n}\bracks{z\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1} +
\pars{n - 1}z^{2}\pars{1 + z}^{n - 2}}}
\\[3mm] = &
\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{2n} -
4\,{n - 1 \over n}\bracks{z^{n - 1}}\pars{1 + z}^{2n - 1} +
4\,{n - 1 \over n}\bracks{z^{n - 2}}\pars{1 + z}^{2n - 2}
\\[3mm] = &
{2n \choose n} -
4\,{n - 1 \over n}{2n - 1 \choose n - 1} +
4\,{n - 1 \over n}{2n - 2 \choose n - 2}
\\[3mm] = &
{2n\pars{2n - 1}\pars{2n - 2}! \over n!\, n!} -
4\,{n - 1 \over n}{\pars{2n - 1}\pars{2n - 2}! \over \pars{n - 1}!\, n!} +
4\,{n - 1 \over n}{\pars{2n - 2}! \over \pars{n - 2}!\, n!}
\\[3mm] = &
\underbrace{\bracks{{2\pars{2n - 1} \over n} -
{4\pars{n - 1}\pars{2n - 1} \over n^{2}} +
{4\pars{n - 1}^{2} \over n^{2}}}}_{\ds{2 \over n}}\
\underbrace{\pars{2n - 2}! \over \pars{n - 1}!\pars{n - 1}!}
_{\ds{2n - 2 \choose n - 1}}
\\[3mm] = &
\bbx{\color{red}{{2 \over n}{2n - 2 \choose n - 1}}}
\end{align}

Comment: Yeah, that's what I got too. But there's a much simpler approach